# Twitter web intents URL shortener

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to user Twitter Web Intents to add a custom tweet functionality to my page. This is a complex page with a lot of query parameters and it goes way over 140 characters. The URL is not getting shortened.

This is the function I'm using:

```
function tweet(image){
    var pageURL = createPreloadURL(image)
    var width  = 575,
        height = 400,
        left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
        top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
        url    = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url='+ encodeURIComponent(pageURL),
        opts   = 'status=1' +
         ',width='  + width  +
         ',height=' + height +
         ',top='    + top    +
         ',left='   + left;
        window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);
}
```

I consoled out the URL string and it seems to be in the right format:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpreload.cfm%3Fproduct_id%3D4420%26year%3D2014%26make_id%3D58%26model_id%3D21604%26diameter%3D17....
```

On the documentation [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents), it the says:

> A fully-qualified URL with a HTTP or HTTPS scheme, URL-encoded. The
>   provided URL will be shortened with Twitter’s t.co to the number of
>   characters specified by short_url_length.
>
> Example Value: http:%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F

I looked in the console on the new window I'm getting this error

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline'
>   'nonce-PfLsh9SlUoh7UKtdZ7mgcA==' 'unsafe-eval' https:". Note that
>   'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present
>   in the source list.

Are there additional steps I need to take to make the url shortener work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem I was having. I was working on a dev link that was an IP address. Twitter's URL shortener apparently doesn't like that. When I tested it on a regular URL, the URL shortened.